# Why is Wednesday Addams named ... Wednesday?

Tags: addams-family

Her mother's name being Morticia, it strikes me odd that her daughter would be named after a day of the week.
Am I missing something?
What is the reasoning behind that character being named Wednesday?

Comment: *Morticia* and *Wednesday* are equally odd names. In fact, these days, *Morticia* would be the stranger of the two. (Sunday Rose Urban, January Jones...)

Comment: Her middle name is Friday. Dunno if that helps.

Comment: @Red_Shadow - Her full name is Wednesday Friday Addams; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_Addams

Comment: Why is your name "Nomkins"?

Comment: @Richard Any idea if the Friday portion also comes from the same poem? "Loving and giving" does not seem to describe her....

Comment: @Red_Shadow - No. There's nothing about her middle name. I'd guess Charles Addams was just trying to be funny.

Comment: My friend worked with a girl named Tuesday.  She would often say, "Hey Tuesday, do you want to go to Friday's on Thursday and get a Sundae?"

Comment: I'm still beating myself up about never having made the connection between Charles Aadams and The Aadams Family until many, MANY years later...

Comment: @Scottie - [Tuesday Weld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuesday_Weld)

Comment: And there already was a "Monday Brown," so he had to go deeper into the week :=-)

Comment: @Scottie I bet jokes like that get pretty Mondayn, I mean mundane, after a while.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

According to [The Addams Family: An Evilution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764953885) Charles Addams named her after the nursery rhyme "[Monday's Child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday%27s_Child)"

> A year earlier, a Manhattan-based company named Aboriginals, Ltd had opted to manufacture stuffed fabric dolls based on the Addams family characters. Addams had been thinking about Morticia as the name of the skeletal beauty in black rags, Gomez was already Gomez, and **a friend suggested that the pallid little girl he was drawing certainly suggested Wednesday, the child of woe from the traditional nursery rhyme. Addams liked it.**

> Monday's child is fair of face,
>
> Tuesday's child is full of grace,
>
> **Wednesday's child is full of woe,**
>
> Thursday's child has far to go,
>
> Friday's child loving and giving,
>
> Saturday's child works hard for a living,
>
> But the child who is born on the Sabbath day
>
> Is fair and wise and good in every way.

Comment: So THAT's where it's from! There have been a couple of Star Trek episodes called "Friday's Child" and such. You have my upvote sir.

Comment: Suddenly a number of book/movie/film things fall into place. I had never heard of this rhyme either but as PointlessSpike already said: Some StarTrek episode titles become clear now. I'm fairly certain there are also some Simpsons episodes related to this.

Comment: If you click the "look inside" cover icon of the book [*The Addams Family: An Evilution*](http://www.amazon.com/Addams-Family-Evilution-Kevin-Miserocchi/dp/0764953885) on amazon, and search for "wednesday's child", p. 81 says Addams was asked about names by a company that wanted to make dolls of the characters (presumably prior to the TV show, when the characters just appeared as *New Yorker* cartoons), and that "a friend had suggested that the pallid little girl he was drawing certainly suggested Wednesday, the child of woe from the traditional nursery rhyme. Addams liked it."

Comment: off topic, but why doesn't the poem refer to the child born on Sunday?

Comment: @Michael most people consider Sunday to be the Sabbath day.

Comment: Most Christians.

Comment: The last verse should read "Is fair and wise and good and gay", from back when "gay" did not have the connotation of "homosexual" it does today.

Comment: I always heard "bonny and blithe and good and gay."

Answer (score 51):

Charles Addams, the creator of the Addams family clearly intended her name to relate to the popular children's rhyme '[Monday's Child'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday's_Child)' *("Monday's child is fair of face, Tuesday's child is full of grace, **Wednesday's child is full of woe***", etc).

---

To back this up, the [original pen sketch](http://addamsfamily.wikia.com/wiki/Wednesday_Addams) that Addams provided to the ABC-TV Network (before the show was aired) specifically describes her as a "child of woe".

> **Child of woe is wane and delicate**... *sensitive and on the quiet side,
>   she loves the picnics and outings to the underground caverns... a
>   solemn child, prim in dress and, on the whole, pretty lost...
>   secretive and imaginative, poetic, seems underprivileged and given to
>   occasional tantrums... has six toes on one foot...*

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I like that you pointed out his specific reference to the rhyme.

Comment: @Nomkins - I'm still at a loss why her middle name was Friday

Comment: "Loving and Giving". She certainly has strong family ties. And in the movie she is constantly exchanging "gifts" with her brother. Exchanging gifts might be a stretch...

Comment: @Richard In many early versions of the poem, Wednesday and Friday attributes were reversed. That seems possibly due to general Christian thoughts of Friday being a bad-luck day. The relation to Wednesday Friday Addams' name is a guess on my part; but since "Wednesday" indeed came from the poem, it seems plausible.

Comment: @user2338816 - They were reversed in the early 1800s. Unless Charles Addams was a history buff, I find it unlikely he'd know that version.

Comment: @Richard Yes, I'm not aware of an acknowledged connection. But the poem was first published in 1838; and at least [one later publication in 1887](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday%27s_Child#Origins) apparently had the two days reversed. It might have been seen many times in many forms in later decades. That's not so far removed from Charles Addams' 1912 birthdate. I'm somewhat familiar with the poem a hundred years later, so it's not a huge stretch to think Addams would also be. He had a fairly decent education and an artistic sense.

Comment: I knew that Wednesday was nameless in the original comics, but not that Charles Addams named her. Wow!

Answer (score 8):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_Addams#Wednesday):

> In Addams' cartoons, which first appeared in The New Yorker, Wednesday
>   and other members of the family had no names. When the characters were
>   adapted to the 1964 television series, Charles Addams gave her the
>   name "Wednesday", based on the [well-known nursery rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday%27s_Child) line,
>   "Wednesday's child is full of woe".

Answer (score 4):

In [a letter in the July 30, 2018 issue of *The New Yorker*](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/07/30/letters-from-the-july-30-2018-issue), Joan Blake from Southern Pines, N.C. takes credit for the name:

> It was a pleasure to see a copy of Charles Addams’s painting “An
>   Addams Family Holiday” printed in the magazine (Sketchbook, July 9th &
>   16th). **I met Addams in New York more than fifty years ago.** I lived in
>   North Carolina, but had travelled to the city for a court case
>   involving the custody of my children. I was staying with my college
>   roommate, and she threw a large party, which Addams attended. I was so
>   depressed that I sat on the couch all evening. Addams sat down beside
>   me and asked what was wrong. I told him. He took my arm, walked me to
>   the elevator, and took me to P. J. Clarke’s. **He made me laugh and told
>   me that the Addams Family was being made into a television show, and
>   that he had no name for the little girl. I said,
>   “Wednesday—Wednesday’s child is full of woe.”** And Wednesday became her
>   name.

Comment: Nice find but is there any reason you didn't edit this into your other answer? It appears to complement it nicely.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I thought about doing that, but I felt this is a different answer.

Comment: Fair enough, was just wondering the reasoning, it's fine either way so doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I remember Morticia explaining why she was named Wednesday Friday as because that's how long she was in labor giving birth to her, from Wednesday to Friday; Wednesday of one week to Friday the next.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your answer? Can you also [edit] why you think the accepted answer contradicts this answer.

Comment: Not necessarily a contradiction.   This could be the in-universe reason stated, while the accepted answer would be the reason why the author picked the name.